# convert yearly data to quarterly data

Tags: python, pandas

I have yearly dataset want to convert into quarterly ones, typically I just want to repeat the yearly values 4 times and assign them to each quarter of that year, who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough detail to yield good answers. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample` and `ffill`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2001-01-01',periods=15, freq='AS'),
                   'Value_1':np.random.randint(0,100,15)})

df=df.set_index('date')

df_out = df.resample('QS').ffill()

print(df_out.head(10))
```

Output:

```
            Value_1
date               
2001-01-01       87
2001-04-01       87
2001-07-01       87
2001-10-01       87
2002-01-01       37
2002-04-01       37
2002-07-01       37
2002-10-01       37
2003-01-01       11
2003-04-01       11
```